# Spring Security form-login for REST applications

Tags: java, ajax, spring, rest, spring-security

I am running into a lil trouble with Spring Security 4.0.

I am using Spring Security to secure a web application and some REST resources that are going to be consumed by a mobile application by using Ajax calls. 
My web application is working out of the box, but my REST services are not too well. The idea is to signin to my app using a form-login in my http, but after a successful signin, I'm not able to access to my protected resources

To get into code, here is my **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 version="3.0">
<display-name>ShakePoint CMS</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/datasource.xml
        /WEB-INF/repositories.xml
        /WEB-INF/facades.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Also, my **spring-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
          xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">


<beans:bean id="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.shakepoint.web.controller.rest.auth.RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
<beans:bean id="restAuthenticationDeniedHandler" class="com.shakepoint.web.controller.rest.auth.RESTAccessDeniedHandler"/>
<beans:bean id="restAuthenticationFailedHandler" class="com.shakepoint.web.controller.rest.auth.RESTAuthenticationFailedHandler"/>
<beans:bean id="restAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.shakepoint.web.controller.rest.auth.RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

<beans:bean id="successAuthenticationHandler" class="com.shakepoint.web.auth.SuccessAuthenticationHandler"/>


<security:http create-session="stateless" 
               pattern="/rest/**" 
               use-expressions="true" 
               entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" 
               authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" >

    <!--<security:intercept-url pattern="/account/signin" access="permitAll()"/>-->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/account/signup" access="permitAll()"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/shop/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_MEMBER')"/>

    <!--<security:http-basic />-->
    <security:form-login login-processing-url="/rest/account/signin"
                         authentication-failure-handler-ref="restAuthenticationFailedHandler"
                         authentication-success-handler-ref="restAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
                         password-parameter="shakepoint_password"
                         username-parameter="shakepoint_username"
                         />
    <!--<security:access-denied-handler ref="restAuthenticationDeniedHandler"/>-->
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
</security:http>



<security:http use-expressions="true" >
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/tech/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_TECHNICIAN')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')"/>
    <security:form-login
        login-page="/signin"
        login-processing-url="/login_to_checkpoint"
        authentication-failure-url="/signin?error"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="successAuthenticationHandler" 
        password-parameter="j_password"
        username-parameter="j_email"/>

    <security:logout logout-success-url="/" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
    <security:csrf/>
</security:http>

<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>
```

On my AuthenticationSuccessHandler and AuthenticationFailedHandler, I am just sending an application/json content type and the object containing the basic authorization value if it was success, and an error message if it was failed.

I'm successfully signing in to my application using the following ajax request

```
$.support.corps = true; 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://192.168.0.7:8080/rest/account/signin',
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(signinData),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if(response.success == true){
                    ...
                }
            },
            error: function(error){
                alert(error);
            }
        });
```

But when I want to access to my protected resources adding the basic authorization header, it returns an unauthorized status from the server. 
I'm also noticing that spring is creating a JSESSION cookie on the response.

My UserDetailsSerivce is working correctly, but, the real question is:

> Am I missing any header? or any extra setup from my server side project?

Please, any help will be fully appreciated

[UPDATE]
This is the Tomcat-7 Log with a successful login with Spring Security

```
2015-10-07 12:16:18 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:151 - Checking match of         request : '/rest/account/signin'; against '/rest/**'
2015-10-07 12:16:18 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /rest/account/signin?  shakepoint_password=tech2&shakepoint_username=tech2@gmail.com at position 1 of 9    in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2015-10-07 12:16:18 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /rest/account/signin?shakepoint_password=tech2&shakepoint_username=tech2@gmail.com at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2015-10-07 12:16:18 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /rest/account/signin?shakepoint_password=tech2&shakepoint_username=tech2@gmail.com at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2015-10-07 12:16:18 DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter:128 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@7cb9682a
2015-10-07 12:16:18 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /rest/account/signin?shakepoint_password=tech2&shakepoint_username=tech2@gmail.com at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2015-10-07 12:16:18 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:151 - Checking match of request : '/rest/account/signin'; against '/rest/account/signin'
2015-10-07 12:16:18 DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:211 - Request is to process authentication
2015-10-07 12:16:18 DEBUG ProviderManager:162 - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2015-10-07 12:16:18 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:634 - Executing prepared SQL query
 2015-10-07 12:16:18 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:569 - Executing prepared SQL statement [select email, password, role from user where email = ?]
2015-10-07 12:16:18 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:110 - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource    
2015-10-07 12:16:18 DEBUG DriverManagerDataSource:162 - Creating new JDBC  DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shakepoint]
2015-10-07 12:16:19 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:332 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2015-10-07 12:16:19 DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:317 - Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@511e4d66: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@fea4fb4d: Username: tech2@gmail.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_TECHNICIAN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_TECHNICIAN
2015-10-07 12:16:19 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:105 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

But, after II try to access to my protected resource I got this:

```
2015-10-07 12:22:09 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:151 - Checking match of request : '/rest/shop/secured_ping'; against '/rest/**'
2015-10-07 12:22:09 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /rest/shop/secured_ping at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2015-10-07 12:22:09 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /rest/shop/secured_ping at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2015-10-07 12:22:09 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /rest/shop/secured_ping at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2015-10-07 12:22:09 DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter:128 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@7cb9682a
2015-10-07 12:22:09 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /rest/shop/secured_ping at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2015-10-07 12:22:09 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:131 - Request 'GET /rest/shop/secured_ping' doesn't match 'POST /rest/account/signin
2015-10-07 12:22:09 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /rest/shop/secured_ping at position 5 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
2015-10-07 12:22:09 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /rest/shop/secured_ping at position 6 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2015-10-07 12:22:09 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /rest/shop/secured_ping at   position 7 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2015-10-07 12:22:09 DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter:100 - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2015-10-07 12:22:09 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /rest/shop/secured_ping at position 8 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2015-10-07 12:22:09 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /rest/shop/secured_ping at position 9 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter:       'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2015-10-07 12:22:09 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:151 - Checking match of request : '/rest/shop/secured_ping'; against '/rest/account/signup'
2015-10-07 12:22:09 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:151 - Checking match of request : '/rest/shop/secured_ping'; against '/rest/shop/**'
2015-10-07 12:22:09 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:218 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /rest/shop/secured_ping; Attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_MEMBER')]
2015-10-07 12:22:09 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:347 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2015-10-07 12:22:09 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:65 - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@629d991f, returned: -1
2015-10-07 12:22:09 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:173 - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at        org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:162)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2522)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2511)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-10-07 12:22:09 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:202 - Calling Authentication entry point.
2015-10-07 12:22:09 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:105 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: Can you please add logging information? generally spring will print log in debug mode for every call.

Comment: Just updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found my own answer this time, after getting into Spring documentation, I found that Spring Security needs a [BasicAuthorizationProcessingFilter](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationFilter.html) to set the SecurityContext on the application

The only thing I did was:

Add the authentication filter

```
<beans:bean id="basicAuthenticationFilter"   class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" ref="authenticationManager"/> 
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1" ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint"/> 
</beans:bean>
```

Changed my http element adding a custom filter child

```
<security:http create-session="stateless" 
               pattern="/rest/**" 
               use-expressions="true" 
               entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" 
               authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" >

    <!--<security:intercept-url pattern="/account/signin" access="permitAll()"/>-->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/account/signup" access="permitAll()"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/shop/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_MEMBER', 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN', 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_TECHNICIAN')"/>
    <security:custom-filter ref="basicAuthenticationFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <security:form-login login-processing-url="/rest/account/signin"
                         authentication-failure-handler-ref="restAuthenticationFailedHandler"
                         authentication-success-handler-ref="restAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
                         password-parameter="shakepoint_password"
                         username-parameter="shakepoint_username"
                         />
    <!--<security:access-denied-handler ref="restAuthenticationDeniedHandler"/>-->
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
</security:http>
```

After these changes, my app security is working out of the box!